# Project flutter does not work on real iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I had a problem that had been bothering me for a long time. I tried to run the project flutter written by android studio on an iphone through the iTerm, but the screen of the Flutter kept coming up white and then flashing back. xcode will work and it will install. I use flutter run -v to see What went wrong, but it showed that everything was fine. Has anyone had this problem？Here's what appears at the end of the run：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdTE3.png)

I try to run flutter doctor, but everything is fine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGkA2.png)
I try to run pod install, and then run flutter run, but it's still not running the project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Nkq.png)